# Files are now readonly

Tags: windows-7

I am using windows 7. All my folders became read-only suddenly and I cannot edit any type of file on my computer.
Yesterday it was fine, but suddenly I discovered this when I am trying to edit some word file.
All folders and files became read-only and I can't edit them

Even if I right-click on the folder and uncheck the read-only option, again it is turning to read-only mode.

I know that attrib command but it is impossible for me to manually uncheck the read only option on every folder..

Is this because of virus? If so, what type of virus it is?.

Comment: If you know about the `attrib` command, surely you also know about wildcards—the `*` character?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a folder's read-only attribute using the Properties dialog box. The only way to change it is with the attrib command.

See the [Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549).